# Overwriting mobile responsive css of canvas woo theme

Tags: css, wordpress, canvas

I am using woo canvas theme for developing a website.I wanted to add custom css for mobile responsive layout.Canvas is responsive but I want to add custom css for changing font-sizes and so on.  I am using following code to add css in my canvas child theme style.css but changes are not reflecting on front end....Please help

```
// For mobile devices
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px)  and (max-device-width : 480px){
        /* custom css ----------- */
 }
 and so on for other devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one of the main benefits of a WordPress child theme is that it can override the original `style.css`. In fact, the only required file in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is a properly-written `style.css`.

But one problem is that Canvas sometimes uses [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), which returns the parent theme styles, instead of [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which returns the child theme styles. To use your child theme styles instead, you can change the functions as needed in your child theme, in `/includes/theme-actions.php`. I had to do that for `layout.css` and `non-responsive.css`.

Using `!important` in CSS is [often a bad idea](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is likely that the CSS you're writing in the child style.css is not overwriting the original style.css file (which has font sizes already written there).

If you include !important to your CSS it might fix the problem, for example change

```
 font-size: 14px;
```

to

```
 font-size: 14px !important;
```

!important overrules any of the other assigned styles for that one. This is the approach you have to take with Child Themes AFAIK (using !important to overrule CSS that is) unless you delete the original style.css file (which kind of defeats the purpose of child themes).